# Packet Generator: Error in run.sh

Tags: dpdk

I executed the below command to run the run.sh file in pktgen-dpdk, which throws the error. I do understand that it does not match the memory requirements. But I did try to allocate a huge-page size of 2048KB. But it still gives me the same error.

The command I tried to execute is:

```
sudo -E ./tools/run.sh 

EAL: Not enough memory available on socket 1! Requested: 2048MB, available: 0MB
EAL: FATAL: Cannot init memory

EAL: Cannot init memory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the host you are trying to run the Pktgen has NUMA, i.e node 0 and node 1, you have to configure hugepages on both NUMA nodes as described in [DPDK Getting Started Guide](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html#use-of-hugepages-in-the-linux-environment), i.e.:

```
echo 2048 > /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
echo 2048 > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

If the host does not have NUMA, you need to fix the Pktgen's arguments. Open `run.sh` script and change `--socket-mem 2048,2048` (i.e. allocate 2K hugepages on NUMA 0 and 2K on NUMA 1) to `--socket-mem 2048` (i.e. allocate 2K hugepages on NUMA 0 only)